# How to use gitfs remote with SaltStack?

Tags: git, github, salt-stack

I want to be able to sync my git repo with salt. I added the following to my master config file:

```
#Git File servers
fileserver_backend:
  - git

gitfs_remotes:
  - https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/salt-formula.git
  - https://git.<company-name>.com/<owner>/<repo>/tree/testing
```

I'm not to sure if I get how it works but it should update after 60 seconds right? I changed some files on my git to be different than whats on my salt master and haven't seen any updates> I ran :

```
sudo salt-run fileserver.update
```

but no change to that file was seen. I'm positive I'm not using this correctly but not too sure what's up since I'm still new to salt.

Answer (score 2):

The file and gitfs roots are merged inside of salt and this is not really visible to you as the files and changes are not reflected in e.g. `/srv/salt`.

Instead the repository contents are located somewhere under `/var/cache/salt` (at least for debian like distros) - nevertheless in your `top.sls` you should be able to use states defined in the gitfs remote. e.g. in the case of the salt formula a state called `salt.master` is available.

A `.sls` file should be either located in gitfs **or** locally in your state tree on the master.